# Rails 3 Mailer and Delayed Job & Heroku

Tags: heroku, delayed-job

I am getting this error
    ArgumentError (name_or_domain is required for info):
I am using delayed_job hirefire and heroku. Here are the lines from my code

```
Notifier.delay.notify(self.artist, commented_on_artist, self.project, self.work_id)
```

When I use the following code everything works perfect

```
Notifier.delay(self.artist, commented_on_artist, self.project, self.work_id).deliver
```

The error is coming from Client.rb in heroku gem from this function 
    # Show info such as mode, custom domain, and collaborators on an app.

```
def info(name_or_domain)
    raise ArgumentError.new("name_or_domain is required for info") unless name_or_domain
    name_or_domain = name_or_domain.gsub(/^(http:\/\/)?(www\.)?/, '')
    doc = xml(get("/apps/#{name_or_domain}").to_s)
    attrs = hash_from_xml_doc(doc)[:app]
    attrs.merge!(:collaborators => list_collaborators(attrs[:name]))
    attrs.merge!(:addons        => installed_addons(attrs[:name]))
end
```

**I just tried out a few things and realized the issue is not with delayed_job it is with hirefire, If i remove the hirefire gem the job gets queued, and I i run the worker manually all works like a charm. I just can't get hirefire to work.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the Cedar stack patch? https://gist.github.com/1082673

Comment: thanks a lot I figured it out while searching. I hope the include it in the Gem. anyways thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

The Cedar stack patch https://gist.github.com/1082673 is a good start, but it needs to be updated to work with the latest heroku-api interface. Here is the patch I am using that is working well.

To use this, you will need to set two Heroku environment variables:

```
heroku config:set APP_NAME=your-heroku-app-name HEROKU_API_KEY=your-heroku-api-key
```

Then add the following:

**config/initializer/hirefire.rb**

```
require 'heroku-api'
module HireFire
  module Environment
    class Heroku < Base

      private

      ##
      # Either retrieves the amount of currently running workers,
      # or set the amount of workers to a specific amount by providing a value
      #
      # @overload workers(amount = nil)
      #   @param [Fixnum] amount will tell heroku to run N workers
      #   @return [nil]
      # @overload workers(amount = nil)
      #   @param [nil] amount
      #   @return [Fixnum] will request the amount of currently running workers from Heroku
      def workers(amount = nil)

        #
        # Returns the amount of Delayed Job
        # workers that are currently running on Heroku
        if amount.nil?
          return heroku.get_ps(ENV['APP_NAME']).body.select {|p| p['process'] =~ /worker.[0-9]+/}.length
        end

        ##
        # Sets the amount of Delayed Job
        # workers that need to be running on Heroku
        return heroku.post_ps_scale(ENV['APP_NAME'], "worker", amount)

      rescue ::Heroku::API::Errors::Error
        HireFire::Logger.message("Worker query request failed with #{ $!.class.name } #{ $!.message }")
        nil
      end

      ##
      # Get the heroku connection. Needs to have the HEROKU_API_KEY in the environment
      def heroku(api_key = nil)
        @heroku ||= ::Heroku::API.new(:api_key => api_key || ENV['HEROKU_API_KEY'])
      end

    end
  end
end
```