# HireFire on Heroku Cedar no getting triggered?

Tags: heroku, cedar, hirefire

I've upgraded an app from 3.2/1.8.7/Bamboo to 3.2/1.9.2/Cedar. Everything seems to be working except HireFire is not getting triggered properly.

Things seem to go smoothly when I run

```
bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

manually, but I can't for the life of me figure it out! I don't even know how to get output to see what the problem might be.

Please help!!

Comment: Try checking your logs with `heroku logs` (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval) and update this question with some additional info.

Comment: That's just the problem. There's nothing in the logs... I don't know how to go about debugging this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got things working. Apparently at the time of this writing, HireFire doesn't work on Cedar (even though it claims to)

## [Rails 3 Mailer and Delayed Job & Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830629/rails-3-mailer-and-delayed-job-heroku)